# How can I remove the drawing layer in leaflet.draw?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.draw

With leaflet.js using leaflet.draw.js after using the draw tool to draw one of the shapes on a custom map. I have a form that pops up which says save or cancel. If the user presses cancel, then I want the drawing to be deleted. For example I was drawing a rectangle.

Here is my current source

```
map.on('draw:created', function(e) {
    var layer = e.layer;
    var type = e.layerType;

    $("#add-drawing").fadeIn(500);

    featureGroup.addLayer(e.layer); // Adds rectangle

    $("a.cancelD").on("click", function() {
        $("#add-drawing").fadeOut(500);

        // THESE ARE THE METHODS I HAVE TRIED TO REMOVE THE RECTANGLE
        map.removeLayer(layer);
        featureGroup.removeLayer(layer);
        map.removeLayer(e);
        featureGroup.removeLayer(e);
    });     
});
```

None of this seems to be working. I can use the toolbox to remove the layer, but then I won't have any information submitted in the form I wish to submit.

How can I remove objects that I have drawn when pressing the cancel button on a form?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you're adding to `featureGroup`, which you say works, you should be removing from `featureGroup` too. Calling `featureGroup.removeLayer(e.layer)` or `featureGroup.removeLayer(layer)` (because `layer` holds a reference to `e.layer`) should work.

Here's a working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/kPvYbH?p=preview

In my opinion the only conclusion can be that your event isn't firing or you're having some sort of weird scoping issue but that can easily be debugged:

```
$("a.cancelD").on("click", function() {
    console.log('Click fired!'); // Seeing this in your console, event works
    console.log(featureGroup); // Should return featureGroup instance, scope ok
    console.log(e.layer); // Should return polygon instance, scope ok

    // If all of the above works, this should too
    featureGroup.removeLayer(e.layer);
});
```

Comment: Massive thumbs up.. The problem was the class, I simply added an id to the cancel button and it worked.. Your live example is what helped me figure it out and the fact you reminded me to check if anything is in the console, which it wasn't. Thank you! Live examples are the best! You might want to edit your answer, to involve the id instead of class :)

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can simply call `.clearLayers()` on your `featureGroup` layer that you created to hold all drawings.

Comment: I also agree that just to clear previous drawn items, it's much simpler to use clearLayers().

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue. For me following solution worked,

featureGroup.clearLayers(e.layer);

Hope this will help someone